# BC-95AC thermal printer not found in PosExplorer.GetDevices()

Tags: c#, thermal-printer, point-of-sale

I have installed drivers for BC-95AC and can find it in my Hardware & Printers and is set to be default.
But when i am trying to access it via PosExplorer. The GetDevices() method does not have this printer in collection.

I want to know how can i fix this. I am no voice with Microsoft Point Of Service or Any expert way to design a sale receipt without using Point Of Service.

Comment: Looks like a product of a company in Karachi.  Give them a call.

Answer (score 0):

To handle devices with POS for.NET, you need a software component called a service object.
It needs to be made according to the interface specification of POS for.NET or OPOS.

Please refer to this site. [POS for .NET Architecture (POS for .NET v1.14 SDK Documentation)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429017(v=winembedded.4).aspx)

Service objects are usually provided by the hardware vendor.
On sites that are considered printer vendors, such software does not appear to be available.
This will not work with POSfor.NET. [BC95AC Thermal Receipt Printer](http://www.blackcopper.net/thermal-receipt-printers/67-bc95ac-thermal-receipt-printer.html)

If you want to print from POS for.NET, switch to the printer of the vendor that provides the service object.

If you want to use this printer, please send the ESC/POS control code directly using the serial port.

Alternatively, you may try using the Windows.Devices.PointOfService interface with the LAN connection option.
**However, I don't know if this method will succeed.**
[Windows.Devices.PointOfService Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.pointofservice)
[PosPrinter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.pointofservice.posprinter)
[Receipt Printer (POSPrinter) - Supported Point of Service Peripherals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-device-support#receipt-printer-posprinter)

> ```
> Connectivity             Support  
> Network and Bluetooth    Windows supports network and Bluetooth connected receipt printers using the Epson ESC/POS printer control language.  
>                          The printers listed below are discovered automatically using POSPrinter APIs.  
>                          Additional receipt printers which provide an ESC/POS emulation may also work but would need to be associated using an out of band pairing process.  
>
>                          Note: slip station and journal stations are not supported through this method.
> ```